# Allow only certain python script's allowed to import and run another script

Tags: python, import

### **What Needs To Happen**

I have two separate python scripts that are referencing a third python script. the first script is allowed to import and run the entire third script however the the second is only allowed to import and run a single function within the third script.

### **The Problem**

The Problem I'm facing is that when I do `import script` then the entire script gets run and in this case fails, I have tried using `if __name__ == '__main__':` however then the first script isn't able to run it.

Is there maybe some variant of `if __name__ == '__main__':` that is able to block one script from running the entire script on import but allow the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own flag.

`s1.py`:

```py
import s3
s3.do_something()
```

`s2.py`:

```py
import s3
s3.full_mode = False
s3.do_something()
```

`s3.py`:

```py
full_mode = True

def do_something():
    if full_mode:
        print("Full mode")
    else:
        print("Mini mode")
```

Comment: aah so simple. unfortunately a part of the problem is on the import line the script will be run. I cannot pass any parameters into it as it will go no further than ```import s3```